# Mysql - Trying to get post id with max number of comments from comment table

Tags: mysql

In MySQL database table comments there are more than 2 billion records and from this table  I have to fetch `post_id` which have max number of comments:

```
select post_id,Count(id) as total from comments group by post_id
```

But this give me all the existing post ids with their no of comment from the above query. And I just want the post id with the max no of comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select post_id, Count(id) as total 
from comments 
group by post_id
order by total desc
limit 1
```